# Python Sequence Syntax

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, sequences

I am new to python and was reading through some code for a Sublime Text plugin and came across some code I am not familiar with.

```
views = [v for v in sublime.active_window().views()]
```

it is the "[v for v" part that I don't understand.  What in the heck is this piece of code doing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Under normal circumstances that is a great idea. However when the boss says write a plugin for this and have it done in two days while working on your other stuff, it isn't exactly a reality.

Comment: SO is here to solve programming problems, not bosses-with-unrealistic-demands problems.

Comment: @millimoose Can you point out the section of the FAQ which says that basic/beginner programming questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's a bit like an expression with an inline for loop, used to create a quick list on the fly. In this case, it's creating a shallow copy of the list returned by `sublime.active_window().views()`.

List comprehensions really shine when you need to transform each value. For example, here's a quick list comprehension to get the first ten perfect squares:

```
[x*x for x in range(1,11)]
```

Comment: Great thanks for the input.  Knowing what exactly it is called will help in learning more about it.

Answer (score 9):

That's a list comprehension.  It is equivalent to (but more efficient than):

```
views = []
for v in sublime.active_window().views():
    views.append(v)
```

Note that in this case, they should have just used `list`:

```
views = list(sublime.active_window().views())
```

There are other types of comprehensions that were introduced in python2.7:

set comprehension:

```
{x for x in iterable}
```

and dict comprehension:

```
{k:v for k,v in iterable_that_yields_2_tuples}
```

So, this is an inefficient way to create a dictionary where all the values are 1:

```
{k:1 for k in ("foo","bar","baz")}
```

Finally, python also supports [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (they're available in python2.6 at least -- I'm not sure when they were introduced):

```
(x for x in iterable)
```

This works like a list comprehension, but it returns an iterable object.  generators aren't particularly useful until you actually iterate over them.  The advantage is that a generator calculates the values on the fly (rather than storing the values in a list which you can then iterate over later).  They're more memory efficient, but they execute slower than list-comps in some circumstances -- In others, they outshine list-comprehensions because it's easy to say -- Just give me the first 3 elements please -- whereas with a list comprehension, you'd have to calculate all the elements up front which is sometimes an expensive procedure.

Comment: Might be good to mention the other kinds of comprehensions Python supports: set {x for x in iterable}, dict {k:v for k,v in iterable}, generator (x for x in iterable)

Comment: Thank you.  It helps to understand that it is just a more efficient loop.

Comment: @dherrin79 -- I've updated my answer a little bit to talk about other types of comprehensions and generator expressions since they are similar.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks.  This is extremely useful information.  I appreciate the time you took to go over the different types of comprehensions.

Comment: I'm liking this answer better than mine. @dherrin79, perhaps you might want to switch the accepted answer.